# How to modify JS code to reuse API call?

Tags: javascript, api, knockout.js

I am working on modifying a web application built by someone else a few years ago. In it, he built an API function in JS which when called, will pull data from SharePoint. I am adding a feature to the application, and will need to do another API call to retrieve some different data. So far, I haven't been able to figure out how to modify the code so that it waits for the ajax call to complete. All of the research that I have done indicates that I should be using a callback to accomplish this, but I am not sure how to implement it properly.

The existing code looks like this:

```
API = function(apiFunction, dataToPost, successCallback) {
    var baseApiUrl = '/SomeWebApp/API/';
    var apiUrl = baseApiUrl + apiFunction;

    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToPost),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
        success: successCallback,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error calling webservice: ' + apiFunction);
        }
    });
}
```

And the call to the API is:

```
API('Lists.asmx/GetStuff', dataToPost, function(data) {
    var options = [];

    $.each(data.d, function(index, value) {
        options.push(new Category(value.Field, value.AnotherField, value.YetAnotherField));
    });

    var viewModel = new ViewModel(options);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

What I need to do is perform the second API call to retrieve the rest of the data, and then create the view model, passing it both sets of data.

What I've tried:

- Moving `options` outside of the callback function, but it seems that because it is asynchronous, the script isn't waiting for the data to be returned. If it did work, I could move `ko.ApplyBindings` outside of the callback function, and just create the new view model with both sets of data
- Assigning the API call to a variable, and having the callback function return `options`. For example:

  ```
  var x = API('Lists.asmx/GetStuff', dataToPost, function(data) {
      var options = [];

      $.each(data.d, function(index, value) {
          options.push(new Category(value.Field, value.AnotherField, value.YetAnotherField));
      });

      return options;
  });
  ```

What would be the best way to modify the code to accomplish this? Should I create a wrapper function that includes the API function as a callback? How would I put that together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution is to put the second API call within the callback function of the first API call. Return statements really don't do anything in an async function unless it's returning a "promise" (see option 2).

```
API('Lists.asmx/GetStuff', dataToPost, function(data) {
    var options = [];

    $.each(data.d, function(index, value) {
        options.push(new Category(value.Field, value.AnotherField, value.YetAnotherField));
    });

    API('Lists/asmx/GetStuff2', secondDataToPost, function(data2){            
        var viewModel = new ViewModel(options, data2);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
});
```

Option 2 - since your API function is already using jQuery to handle the ajax you can change it to return the result of the ajax call, a type of deferred object, on which you can call .done to attach a callback method instead. [jquery-deferred-and-promise walkthrough](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/)

```
API = function(apiFunction, dataToPost, successCallback) {
    var baseApiUrl = '/SomeWebApp/API/';
    var apiUrl = baseApiUrl + apiFunction;

    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}
```

The returned deferred object can be used similarly to the passed in callback by using the .done method on the object.

```
API('Lists.asmx/GetStuff', dataToPost).done(function(data) {
    callback stuff...
});
```

This is a little more flexible and can let you do chaining and simultaneous execution like the following where both api calls get sent at the same time instead of having to wait for the response from the first call before sending the second one.

```
$.when(
    API('Lists.asmx/GetStuff', dataToPost),
    API('Lists.asmx/GetStuff2', dataToPost2)
).done(function(data1, data2) {
    var options = [];

    $.each(data.d, function(index, value) {
        options.push(new Category(value.Field, value.AnotherField, value.YetAnotherField));
    });

    var viewModel = new ViewModel(options, data2);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! I used the second example, which worked great. The only snafu that I ran into was it didn't seem to be passing the results from the API calls into each of the arguments for the function in .done. I ended up just using `arguments[0][0]` and `arguments[1][0]` to grab the data. Still having some problems getting the viewmodel working in this project, but it's coming along!

Comment: Ah yes I realized later that my example was slightly off. The structure of the return objects changes a little in the .done function of a $.when. Instead of data.d it's probably something like data[0].d. Using the arguments thing should work just as well though.

Comment: That's correct, I used `.d` in my code :). The help was very much appreciated, I was beating my head against the wall for quite a while with that one :)